# Related physical processes of a toy model in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, scattering

I am dealing with a toy model in $d = 6$ (or $d = 6 - 2\epsilon$ in dimensional regularisation) with the Lagrangian
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L} = \dfrac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi + \dfrac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\varphi^* \partial^{\mu}\varphi + \dfrac{1}{2} m^2 \varphi^2 - g \varphi^* \varphi\hspace{0.1mm}\phi - \dfrac{\lambda}{3!}\phi^3 \; ,
\end{align}
where $\phi$ is a real scalar field and $\varphi$ a complex scalar field.

Aside from the "unphysical" choice of dimension, what real physical processes (e.g. decay, scattering) involving types of particles can such a theory describe and what types of particles (e.g. scalar particles such as mesons) relate to the fields $\phi$ and $\varphi$?

Comment: One gathers you are happy with all d=4 interpretations? you start with a massless scalar $\phi$ and a "charged" massive scalar $\varphi$ which you could resolve to $\varphi^{\pm}$ if desired. They connect by cubic couplings, preserving charge.

Comment: It's a legitimate QFT in its own right. It shows all the features that a $d=4$ QFT would show except for infrared divergences. It's a fantastic toy model to play with in order to learn all the technicalities of QFT calculations.

Comment: you can find the answer of your first question just buy drawing vertices  from your interaction terms.  so $\phi$ self -interaction has a 3 leg vertex, and $\varphi$ does not interact with itself but it interacts with $\phi$ with 3 leg vertex where 2 of the legs for $\varphi$. so by using those vertices you can find plethora of interaction and scattering  and decay processes.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/684669/2451